# laravel oauth authorize error while php version change

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, oauth, laravel-8, laravel-passport

[image: laravel-8 oauth authorize error while php version change]

I'm trying to setup OAuth to work with my application that is being developed locally on my machine. Everything was working perfect with authorization UNTIL I moved from using localhost to another domain name (still local to my machine.) Now I'm getting the following error.

when i redirect one project to another project for authentication while i get this error.
now how is solved ?

Comment: This is a parse/syntax error, so it's a problem with the syntax of the code itself. You mention PHP version change, what version is it changing from and to?

Comment: i change the php version 8.1.10 to 8.0.23

Comment: You might need to delete the vendor folder and rerun `composer install` in the new directory, as long as composer is running PHP 8.0.23. Line 259 is `$user = preg_replace_callback($user_pattern, Uri::urlEncodeMatch(...), $user);` which was changed when removing PHP 8.0 support.

Comment: i also had try it but it's not working